# rest web service for soap client, is that possible?

Tags: rest

Platform - Java, Ubuntu (apache preferred)

I have a situation where i would like to implement rest web service for soap client. Baiscally this service will be simulating a behavior of real service. Is that possible?

If yes, another question, Is Axis2 good enough for rest web service, if not what is easiest alternative.

My simulator is very simple where it will respond with a xml response based on xpath parsing of request.

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely possible. SOAP requests are sent using POST method so you just need to build REST resource and respond with a proper SOAP response xml to POST requests.
I've build something similar using RESTeasy which is pretty simple.

https://sourceforge.net/p/soaprest-mocker/

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago, I read this [tutorial](http://wso2.org/library/3726) and implemented some services based on this architecture (Axis2+WSDL+RESTful). It works fine. But I will not assume it as the best architecture for everything ("One size fits all"), but it's easy to deploy, test and use.

Try it and give us your opinion!