# Access SOAP webservice from REST client

Tags: javascript, json, rest, soap, xml-parsing

How to give request to a soap web service from a rest client.

Suppose the soap web service does addition of two numbers, the data from the rest will be in the form of JSON.

How to send this data and get the result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621231/rest-web-service-for-soap-client-is-that-possible

Comment: I went through that link already ,unfortunately i couldnt understand.I am a noob in this area. The only thing i could find in the internet is an external application which does the parsing of JSON to XML. It would be helpful if u could explain me with a simple example.

Comment: nah, I don't think so, that's what tutorials are for

Answer (score 0):

we cannot access to the soap services by using rest client api because we cannot build the soap xml and pass the data or i think you **need to create a class the reflect the soap xml** and you need to give our **data to soap body** and pass the **soap object** to the **rest client**